# Why does URL require forced unwrapping or a default value here?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a router class that will populate some routes when instantiated:

```
private func populateRoutes() {
     routes.addRoute(url: URL(string: Resource.home.rawValue)!, actions: [RequestMethod.head: headAction, RequestMethod.get: getAction])
     routes.addRoute(url: URL(string: Resource.test.rawValue)!, actions: [RequestMethod.get: getAction])
}
```

I also have an enum class to store the string representation of a route:

```
public enum Resource: String {
    case home = "/index"
    case test = "/simple_get"
}
```

I don't understand why Xcode is giving me an error for not providing a default value(??) or use forced unwrap(!)

Comment: If you pass the URL initializer an invalid string, it can't create a valid URL and you get nil instead.  So since there's the chance of it failing, it's an optional.

Answer (score 1):

The string constructor for URL returns an optional URL, so the compiler is asking you to provide a non-optional parameter for the call to addRoute.

The docs for URL init?(string: String) [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1779737-init) say that it returns nil if a URL cannot be formed because of the string that's supplied.